# How to focus the currently selected intem in a horizontalPager?

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os, horizontal-pager

I am working on an wearOS app with a `HorizonalPager`, which has a `ScalingLazyColumn` in each of its pages. For all who aren't so familiar with wearOS design elements: A `ScalingLazyColumn` is basicly just a vertical List of different items. in my case some `Card`s. The code looks somewhat like this:

```
HorizontalPager(state=pagerState){
val listState = rememberScalingLazyListState()
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

ScalingLazyColumn(
state= listState,
modifier= modifier
.onRotaryScrollEvent {
   coroutineScope.launch {
      listState.scrollBy(it.verticalScrollPixels)
      listState.animateScrollBy(0f)}
                               
      true
   }
.focusRequester(focusRequester)
.focusable()
){

//in here are my items
}
}
```

In order for the Code to accept the rotary Input of smartwatches, I need the `onRotaryScrollEvent` to scroll the list.But for this to work, the List must have focus. The problem with this code is, that just the firstly loaded page is focused and nothing else.

So I would need some way to just focus the currently selected page of this `HorizontalPager.` Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The horologist project has a wrapper for HorizontalPager that does this automatically, as well as the page indicator.

https://github.com/google/horologist/blob/4e139ff18cc3bbd275088a9f596883c3ef7bbc06/compose-layout/src/main/java/com/google/android/horologist/compose/pager/PagerScreen.kt#L48

You can use this directly, or copy the approach.

The critical code is HierarchicalFocusCoordinator, which can be hooked into navigation or pager scrolling to focus the right screen.

```
        HorizontalPager(
            modifier = modifier,
            state = state,
            flingBehavior = HorizontalPagerDefaults.flingParams(state),
        ) { page ->
            ClippedBox(state) {
                HierarchicalFocusCoordinator(requiresFocus = { page == state.currentPage }) {
                    content(page)
                }
            }
        }
```

Within your content, when you use Compose's `rememberActiveFocusRequester()` it will follow the current page.